# If $\cos^{-1}x - \tan^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}=\pi$, then what are the possible values of $x$?

Tags: trigonometry

If $\cos^{-1}x - \tan^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}=\pi$, then what are all the possible values of $x$? Please explain in detail.

Comment: $X=(-1,-\sqrt{3}/2,-1/2)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation is defined for $x\neq 0$. Set $\theta=\arccos x$. This means $\cos \theta=x,\enspace 0\le x\le \pi,\enspace\theta\neq\dfrac\pi2$.

Now, $\sin\theta=\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta}=\sqrt{1-x^2}\;$ since $\sin\theta\ge 0$ on $[0,\pi]$. Thus 
$$\tan\theta=\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}x,\enspace\text{whence}\enspace\arctan\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}x\equiv\theta\mod\pi. $$

As $\;\arctan t\in \Bigl(-\dfrac\pi2,\dfrac\pi2\Bigr)$ by definition, two cases are possible:

- Either $0\le\theta <\dfrac\pi2$ (corresponding to $x>0$). Then $\;\arctan\dfrac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}x=\theta$ and the equation reduces to $0=\pi$, which has no solution
- Or $\dfrac\pi2<\theta\le\pi\;$ $\;(x<0$). Then $\;\arctan\dfrac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}x=\theta-\pi$, and  the equation reduces to $\pi=\pi$, which is always valid. Hence the solutions are $\;\color{red}{0<x\le \pi}$.

Comment: But the answer is closed interval [-1,0].please explain further

Comment: @Ujjwal: I had inadvertently changed the $-$ sign in the equation with a $+$, sorry! I changed my answer. However, note the value  $0$ is not correct.

Comment: It comes from the definition of the $\arctan$ function. I've added an explanation. Is that clearer now?

Comment: In case 1 how did you get 0= $pi$? And In case 2 how why did you take arctan$\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}$ as $theta$-$pi$ and not $pi$ - $theta$? And after that how did you get $pi$=$pi$? And does narsimham's explanation convince you? Because according to him 0 should come in the answer.

Comment: IN case $1$, I replaced the left-hand side with $\theta_\theta$ (which is $0$, if I'm not mistaken…). In case 2,  you cant, because it has to be congruent modulo $\pi$  to $\theta$, not to $-\theta$. As to $\pi=\pi$, I simply replaced again in the left-hand side.

Comment: I'm simply clueless like how can you replace them and what is congruent modulo in case 2

Comment: @Ujjwal: In case 2, the l.h.s. becomes $\theta-(\theta-\pi)$, i.e. $\pi$, whence the equality. For your other point, see the third line in my answer: $\;\arctan\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}x\equiv\color{red}{\theta}\mod\pi$ and by definition $-\theta+\pi\equiv \color{red}-\theta\mod\pi$

Answer (score 0):

As $0\le\cos^{-1}x\le\pi$

As $\tan^{-1}\dfrac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}x=\cos^{-1}x-\pi,$

$-\pi\le\tan^{-1}\dfrac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}x\le0\implies-\dfrac\pi2\le\tan^{-1}\dfrac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}x\le0$ as $\tan^{-1}y\in\Bigl(-\dfrac\pi2,\dfrac\pi2\Bigr)$

$\implies x<0$

Using [How do I prove that $\arccos(x) + \arccos(-x)=\pi$ when $x \in [-1,1]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1224415/how-do-i-prove-that-arccosx-arccos-x-pi-when-x-in-1-1),

$\tan^{-1}\dfrac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}x=\cos^{-1}x-\pi=-\cos^{-1}(-x)$

Let $y=-x>0,$

$\implies\cos^{-1}y=-\tan^{-1}\dfrac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}{-y}=\tan^{-1}\dfrac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}y$

Let $\cos^{-1}y=u\implies0\le u<\dfrac\pi2$ and $\cos u=y$

and  $\dfrac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}y=\tan u\implies\tan^{-1}\dfrac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}y=u=\cos^{-1}y$

So, the only requirement is $x<0$

Comment: Didn't get it sorry please give it another shot and explain me the basics

Comment: @Ujjwal, Please pinpoint your confusion.

Comment: The answer to the question is [-1,0].

Comment: @Ujjwal, So, it should be as $\cos^{-1}x$ is defined for $[-1,1]$  and we need $x<0$