# Find $x$ such that $\sin(\arccos(\tan(\arcsin x))))=x$

Tags: trigonometry, triangulation

Find all real numbers $x$ such that $$\sin(\arccos(\tan(\arcsin x))))=x.$$

Using [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin(arccos(tan(arcsinx)))) we get $$\sin(\arccos(\tan(\arcsin x))))=\sqrt{\dfrac{2x^2-1}{x^2-1}}$$

Why? Because some case such  $\arcsin{x}=\arccos{(1-x^2)}$ or $\pi-\arccos{(\sqrt{1-x^2})}.$

I think the answer is $x=\dfrac{\sqrt{5}\pm 1}{2}.$ Am I right?

Comment: I assume $\arcsin(x)$ is only defined for $|x|\le1$ here, right?  In other words, $\arcsin\left(\frac{\sqrt5+1}2\right)$ makes no sense...

Comment: Thanks .I understand,so $x=\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$ is only root

Comment: No, you had it wrong in the first place, as your $\pm$ sign was placed wrong.  See Jan Eerland's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\arcsin x=y\,$, therfore $\sin y=x$ and $\cos y=+\sqrt{1-x^2}\,$ as $\,-\dfrac\pi2\le y\le\dfrac\pi2$
we have
$$\tan(\arcsin x)=\tan(y)=\dfrac x{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
thus
$$x=\sin\left(\arccos\dfrac x{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)$$

set $$\arccos\left(\dfrac x{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)=u\,\quad ,\quad0\le u\le\pi$$

we can write $$\sin u=+\sqrt{1-\dfrac{x^2}{1-x^2}}=\sqrt{\dfrac{1-2x^2}{1-x^2}}$$

So, we have $$x=\sqrt{\dfrac{1-2x^2}{1-x^2}}$$ which is $\ge0$

Squaring we get
$$x^2(1-x^2)=1-2x^2\iff x^4-3x^2+1=0$$

Solve for $x^2$

Answer (score 1):

Let's try dismantling $\sin(\arccos(\tan(\arcsin x)))$.

Note that $\sin(\arccos t)\ge0$, so we can apply
$$
\sin(\arccos t)=\sqrt{1-(\cos(\arccos t))^2}=\sqrt{1-t^2}
$$

Thus we have a first reduction
$$
\sqrt{1-(\tan(\arcsin x))^2}=x
$$
which tells you that $x\ge0$.

Now let's tackle $\tan(\arcsin x)$ over the interval $[0,1)$. We have
$$
\tan(\arcsin x)=
\frac{\sin\arcsin x}{\cos\arcsin x}=\frac{x}{\cos\arcsin x}
$$
Again, $\cos(\arcsin x)\ge0$, so we have
$$
\cos(\arcsin x)=\sqrt{1-(\sin(\arcsin x))^2}=\sqrt{1-x^2}
$$

Thus the equation is
$$
\sqrt{1-\biggl(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\biggr)^2}=x
$$
or
$$
1-\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}=x^2
$$
Recall that only solutions in the interval $[0,1)$ can be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin(\arccos(\tan(\arcsin x))))=x$$ implies

$$\tan(\arcsin x))=\cos(\arcsin(x))=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$$

and in general

$$\tan(\arcsin x))=\pm\frac x{\sqrt{1-x^2}}.$$

Then

$$1-x^2=\pm x.$$

As $|x|\le1$, two candidates are $$\pm\frac{\sqrt5-1}2,$$ but only the positive sign holds. (Denoting the quadrants in Roman numbers, $+\to I\to+\to I\to+$ or $-\to IV\to-\to II\to+$.)

Comment: $\tan(\arcsin x)=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$ seems incorrect

Comment: @McCheng: no, you apply $\cos(\arcsin())$ to the two members of the original equation. It is clear that this is not an identity, as the $\tan$ would magically turn to a $\cos$; the next line is an identity. The upvotes to this remark are undue.

Answer (score 0):

$$\arccos(\tan(\arcsin x)))=\arcsin x=\text{sign}(x)\cdot\arccos\sqrt{1-x^2}$$

If $x\ge0,$ $$\tan(\arcsin x))=\sqrt{1-x^2}$$

If $\arcsin x=y,\sin y= x,0\le x\le\dfrac\pi2\implies\cos y=+\sqrt{1-x^2}$

$\sqrt{1-x^2}=\tan(y)=\dfrac x{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

$\iff1-x^2=x$

If $x<0,$

using [How do I prove that $\arccos(x) + \arccos(-x)=\pi$ when $x \in [-1,1]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1224415/how-do-i-prove-that-arccosx-arccos-x-pi-when-x-in-1-1),

$$\arccos(\tan(\arcsin x)))=-\arccos\sqrt{1-x^2}=\pi-\arccos(-\sqrt{1-x^2})$$

$$\arccos(-\sqrt{1-x^2})=\pi-\arccos(\tan(\arcsin x)))=\arccos(-\tan(\arcsin x)))$$

$$\sqrt{1-x^2}=\tan(\arcsin x)$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks,but $x<0$ is ugly than $x>0$ ,so I have Trouble

Comment: @functionsug, For $x<0;$  $$\arcsin x=-\arccos\sqrt{1-x^2}$$  Now use http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1224415/how-do-i-prove-that-arccosx-arccos-x-pi-when-x-in-1-1

Comment: so $\arccos(\tan(arcsinx)))=-\arccos{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\pi-\arccos{(-\sqrt{1-x^2})}$ then?

Comment: @functionsug, Let me update the answer

Comment: @functionsug, Updated the answer