# In a triangle $a:b:c =4:5:6$, then $3A+B$ equals to?

Tags: triangles

In the above question $a,b,c$ are sides of triangle and $A,B,C$ are angles. The correct answer is $\pi$ but I am getting $\pi - C$.

Comment: Show us your working so we can point out where you're wrong.

Comment: Your answer must be wrong since this would mean $A=0$ (use $A+B+C=\pi (180^0$ in a triangle) and  you claim $3A+B+C=\pi$). But, yes, show your working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\cos{A}=\frac{5^2+6^2-4^2}{2\cdot5\cdot6}=\frac{3}{4}.$$
Thus, $$\sin{A}=\sqrt{1-\frac{9}{16}}=\frac{\sqrt{7}}{4}<\frac{1}{\sqrt2},$$
which says that $A<45^{\circ}$, which gives that $2A$ is an acute angle
and $$\sin2A=2\cdot\frac{\sqrt7}{4}\cdot\frac{3}{4}=\frac{3\sqrt7}{8}.$$
In another hand, $$\cos{C}=\frac{4^2+5^2-6^2}{2\cdot4\cdot5}=\frac{1}{8},$$
which gives $$\sin{C}=\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{64}}=\frac{3\sqrt7}{8}.$$
Thus, $C=2A$ and
$$3A+B=2A+A+B=C+A+B=180^{\circ}$$
and we are done!

Comment: Thanks Michael. It helped. :-)

Comment: @Muhammad Ali Zafar Welcome!

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

We have $\dfrac a4=\dfrac b5=\dfrac c6=k$(say)

$\implies a=4k$ etc.

Use cosine formula

$$\cos A=\dfrac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}=\cdots=\dfrac{45}{60}>\dfrac12\implies0<A<60^\circ$$

and $$\cos B=\dfrac9{16}$$

$$\cos3A=-\dfrac9{16}$$

Now use [How do I prove that $\arccos(x) + \arccos(-x)=\pi$ when $x \in [-1,1]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1224415/how-do-i-prove-that-arccosx-arccos-x-pi-when-x-in-1-1)

Comment: I used cosine formula but i am not getting the answer. Help

Comment: Sahiba I dont know how to write the process here. Can you please solve it.

Comment: @MuhammadAliZafar, Please find the updated answer.