# Definite integral involving odd and even function.

Tags: integration, functions, definite-integrals, even-and-odd-functions

$$\int_{\frac {-1}{\sqrt 3}}^{\frac {1}{\sqrt 3}} \frac {x^4}{1-x^4}\cos^{-1}(\frac {2x}{1+x^2})dx$$

As the limits are $a$ and $-a$, I try to figure out what is $f(-x)$,but the function is neither becoming $-f(x)$ or $f(x)$.
Note that ,I first converted $cos^{-1}x$ to $sin^{-1}x$.

Comment: Please use Mathjax instead of pictures.

Comment: @Andrew Li Can you please edit my post,actually i donot yet fully acquainted with jax

Comment: I would recommend getting at least acquainted with it before posting because I don't have the time currently to do so. Have you seen [the basic tutorial on Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)?

Comment: Thanks @Leyla Alkan Could you tell me how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Like [Evaluate the integral $\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \frac{\sin^3x}{\sin^3x+\cos^3x}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439851/evaluate-the-integral-int-frac-pi2-0-frac-sin3x-sin3x-cos3xdx/439856#439856),

$$I=\int_{-a}^a\dfrac{x^{2n}}{1-x^{2n}}\arccos\dfrac{2x}{1+x^2}dx$$

$$=\int_{-a}^a\dfrac{x^{2n}}{1-x^{2n}}\arccos\dfrac{(-2x)}{1+x^2}dx$$

Using [How do I prove that $\arccos(x) + \arccos(-x)=\pi$ when $x \in [-1,1]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1224415/how-do-i-prove-that-arccosx-arccos-x-pi-when-x-in-1-1),

$$I+I=\pi\int_{-a}^a\dfrac{x^{2n}}{1-x^{2n}}dx$$

Now $$\int\dfrac{x^{2n}}{1-x^{2n}}dx=\int\dfrac{dx}{1-x^{2n}}-\int dx$$