# Strange trigonometric simplification? $\cos^{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{3\sqrt{7}}\right)-\frac12\pi = \sin^{-1}\frac{1}{3\sqrt{7}}$

Tags: trigonometry

I don't understand this simplification:

$$\begin{align}
\cos^{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{3\sqrt{7}}\right)-\frac12\pi 
&= \left(\pi - \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{3\sqrt{7}}\right)\right) - \frac12\pi \\[4pt]
&= \frac12 \pi - \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{3\sqrt{7}}\right) \\[4pt]
&= \sin^{-1}\frac{1}{3\sqrt{7}}
\end{align}$$

Am I not noticing any simple trigonometric identity?

Comment: Maybe $\,\arccos(x)+\arccos(-x)=\pi\,$?

Comment: @Blue Thanks for the edit. Much more legible now!

Comment: @dxiv You are right. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1224415/how-do-i-prove-that-arccosx-arccos-x-pi-when-x-in-1-1

Comment: @Ramana  Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details [HERE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first step

$$\cos^{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{3\sqrt{7}}\right)-\frac12\pi 
= \left(\pi - \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{3\sqrt{7}}\right)\right) - \frac12\pi $$

we are using that for $0\le x\le \pi$

$$\arccos (-\theta)=\pi-\arccos \theta$$

which is trivial from the definition of $\arccos \theta$ dependin for the fact that $\cos \theta = \cos (-\theta)$.

For the second step note that for $0\le x\le \pi/2$

$$\theta = \frac{\pi}2-\arccos x\implies \sin \theta=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}2-\arccos x\right)=\cos (\arccos x)=x$$

therefore

$$\theta = \arcsin x$$