# Expression for $\cos^{-1}x\pm\cos^{-1}y$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

As mentioned in [Proof for the formula of sum of arcsine functions $\arcsin x+\arcsin y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672575/proof-for-the-formula-of-sum-of-arcsine-functions-arcsin-x-arcsin-y?noredirect=1&lq=1) for $\sin^{-1}x+\sin^{-1}y$

$$
\sin^{-1}x+\sin^{-1}y=
\begin{cases}
\sin^{-1}( x\sqrt{1-y^2} + y\sqrt{1-x^2}) \;\;;x^2+y^2 \le 1 \\\
\pi - \sin^{-1}( x\sqrt{1-y^2} + y\sqrt{1-x^2}) \;\;;x^2+y^2 > 1, 0< x,y \le 1\\
-\pi - \sin^{-1}( x\sqrt{1-y^2} + y\sqrt{1-x^2}) \;\;;x^2+y^2 > 1, -1< x,y \le 0
\end{cases}
$$
Can we have similar expression for $\cos^{-1}x\pm\cos^{-1}y$ ?

Comment: I mean $\arccos(x) = \pi/2 - \arcsin(x)$ which you can surely use to reformulate your expressions in terms of $\arccos$.

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1224415/how-do-i-prove-that-arccosx-arccos-x-pi-when-x-in-1-1

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, to get rid of all those cases, we can write:
$$\sin^{-1}x\pm\sin^{-1}y=\text{atan2}(x\sqrt{1-y^2}\pm y\sqrt{1-x^2},\ \sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-y^2}\mp xy)$$
and:
$$\cos^{-1}x\pm\cos^{-1}y=\text{atan2}(y\sqrt{1-x^2}\pm x\sqrt{1-y^2},\ xy\mp\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-y^2})$$

See [atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2).

Comment: thanx. but the cases are really important and my doubt is there !

Comment: How are the cases important, and which doubt do you have @ss1729? Note that we have a formula that transforms an angle uniquely into x,y. Arcsin and arccos don't do the reverse but atan2 does.