# $\cos^{-1}x+\cos^{-1}y=\cos^{-1}\Big(xy-\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-y^2}\Big)$ true for all $x$?

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

> $\cos^{-1}x+\cos^{-1}y=\cos^{-1}\Big(xy-\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-y^2}\Big)$ true for all $x$ ?

**My Attempt**

Let $a=\cos^{-1}x$, $b=\cos^{-1}y\implies$$\cos a=x$, $\cos b=y$ and $a,b\in[0,\pi]\implies a+b\in[0,2\pi]$
$$
\cos(a+b)=\cos a\cos b-\sin a\sin b=xy-\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-y^2}\\=\cos\bigg[\cos^{-1}\Big(xy-\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-y^2}\Big)\bigg]\\
a+b=\color{red}{\cos^{-1}x+\cos^{-1}y=2n\pi\pm\cos^{-1}\Big(xy-\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-y^2}\Big)}
$$
**Case 1:** $a+b\in[0,\pi)$
$$
\cos^{-1}x+\cos^{-1}y=\cos^{-1}\Big(xy-\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-y^2}\Big)
$$

**Case 2:** $a+b\in[\pi,2\pi]$
$$
\cos^{-1}x+\cos^{-1}y=2\pi-\cos^{-1}\Big(xy-\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-y^2}\Big)
$$
**Case 1-:** $a+b\in[0,\pi)$

**Note** I have checked a possible solution to this in [link](https://www.math-only-math.com/arccos-x-plus-arccos-y.html), but it gives a different expression differ from my attempt.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3027787/expression-for-cos-1x-pm-cos-1y

Comment: @labbhattacharjee thanx. but the given post does not say anything about all cases for the expression nor the domain of $x,y$ for which the given expression is valid !. I hardly find any post on the complete expression for $\cos^{-1}x+\cos^{-1}y$ on internet.

Comment: For $x=y=-1$, the LHS is $2\pi$, the RHS is $0$.

Comment: @Andrei For $x=y=-1\implies a=b=\pi$. RHS=$2\pi-\cos^{-1}1=2\pi=LHS$, it is **case 2**. srry abt that, just edited the domain.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee could you please comment on my attempt ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Principal values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values) and  [Why it's true? $\arcsin(x) +\arccos(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1116974/why-its-true-arcsinx-arccosx-frac-pi2),

$\cos^{-1}x+\cos^{-1}y\le2\pi$

$$\cos^{-1}x+\cos^{-1}y=\cos^{-1}(xy-\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)})$$

will hold true if $\cos^{-1}x+\cos^{-1}y\le\pi$

$\iff\sin^{-1}x+\sin^{-1}y\ge0\iff\sin^{-1}x\ge-\sin^{-1}y=\sin^{-1}(-y)$

$\iff x\ge -y\iff x+y\ge0$

$$\cos^{-1}x+\cos^{-1}y=2\pi-\cos^{-1}(xy-\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)})$$

will hold true if $\cos^{-1}x+\cos^{-1}y>\pi$

$\iff\sin^{-1}x+\sin^{-1}y<0\iff x+y<0$

Comment: Thanks. I just have one more query. Could u please confirm that,
$\cos^{-1}x-\cos^{-1}y=\begin{cases}\cos^{-1}\bigg(xy+\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-y^2}\bigg),\;x-y\leq 0\\ -2\pi+\cos^{-1}\bigg(xy+\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-y^2}\bigg),\;x-y> 0\end{cases}$

Comment: @ss1729, First replace $y$ with $-z$ in the identity derived in the answer. Then use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1224415/how-do-i-prove-that-arccosx-arccos-x-pi-when-x-in-1-1