# Radically different answers for $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\arccos\frac{\sqrt{1 - x^3} - \sqrt{1 + x^3}}{2}\right)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry, solution-verification, math-software

> Find the derivative with respect to $x$ of $$\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1 - x^3}  - \sqrt{1 + x^3}}{2}\right).$$

**Here's my work:**

Substituting $x^3 = \cos(2\theta):$
$$\begin{aligned}\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1 - x^3}  - \sqrt{1 + x^3}}{2}\right) &= \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1 - \cos(2\theta)}  - \sqrt{1 + \cos(2\theta)}}{2}\right)\\& = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2\sin^2\theta}  - \sqrt{2\cos^2\theta}}{2}\right)\\& = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin\theta - \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\cos\theta\right) \\& = \cos^{-1}\left(\sin\theta\cos(\pi/4) - \sin(\pi/4)\cos\theta\right) \\& = \cos^{-1}\sin\left(\theta - \frac{\pi}{4} \right)\\& = \cos^{-1}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}2 - \theta + \frac{\pi}{4} \right)\\& = \frac{3\pi}4 - \theta \\& = \frac{3\pi}4 - \frac12\cos^{-1}\left(x^3\right).\end{aligned}$$

Differentiating this gives
$$\boxed{\frac{3x^2}{2\sqrt{1 - x^6}}}.$$
So far so good... My textbook also shows this answer.

---

But the problem is that [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=d%2Fdx+arccos%28%7B%5Csqrt%7B1-x%5E3%7D+-+%5Csqrt%7B1%2Bx%5E3%7D%7D%2F2%29++++++), [this](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cfrac%7Bd%7D%7Bdx%7D%5Cleft(%5Ccos%5E%7B-1%7D%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B%5Csqrt%7B1%20-%20x%5E%7B3%7D%7D%20%20-%20%5Csqrt%7B1%20%2B%20x%5E%7B3%7D%7D%7D%7B2%7D%5Cright)%5Cright)?or=input), [this](https://www.derivative-calculator.net/), and the symPy package of Python all give *this* clunky result $$\boxed{-\frac{-\frac{3x^{2}}{2\sqrt{1-x^{3}}}-\frac{3x^{2}}{2\sqrt{1+x^{3}}}}{2\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{4}\left(\sqrt{1-x^{3}}-\sqrt{1+x^{3}}\right)^{2}}}}$$ (not even neutralising the three negative signs) instead of the above simpler one.

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=+-%28-%283+x%5E2%29%2F%282+sqrt%281+-+x%5E3%29%29+-+%283+x%5E2%29%2F%282+sqrt%281+%2B+x%5E3%29%29%29%2F%282+sqrt%281+-+1%2F4+%28sqrt%281+-+x%5E3%29+-+sqrt%281+%2B+x%5E3%29%29%5E2%29%29++%3D++%7B3x%5E2%7D%2F%7B2%5Csqrt%7B1+-+x%5E6%7D%7D) and [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0ivuehr6cu) shows that these two expressions have the same domain $(-1,1)$ and are identically equal.

Why do these software not give the answer in simplified form?

Comment: You should get used to the fact that there are no *one* 'simplified form'. If you see the software return equal results then it's fine.

Comment: My guess is that these softwares are worried about complex number cases, or some domain that you don't really care about.

Comment: Actually, [many values work](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=N%5B+-%28-%283+x%5E2%29%2F%282+sqrt%281+-+x%5E3%29%29+-+%283+x%5E2%29%2F%282+sqrt%281+%2B+x%5E3%29%29%29%2F%282+sqrt%281+-+1%2F4+%28sqrt%281+-+x%5E3%29+-+sqrt%281+%2B+x%5E3%29%29%5E2%29%29+-++%7B3x%5E2%7D%2F%7B2%5Csqrt%7B1+-+x%5E6%7D%7D%2C22%5D%2Cx%3D2) for both functions in your Wolfram Alpha link. The numerical comparison for these cases gives a very small complex number, so it may be a problem with its computation

Comment: This doesn't answer the *why* part, but if you let $\,a = \sqrt{1-x^3}, b = \sqrt{1+x^3}\,$, then equating the two expressions simplifies to $\,a+b = \sqrt{4 - (a-b)^2}\,$ which is easy to verify.

Comment: Both expressions are equal on $(-1,1)$ but if you consider values of $x\in \mathbb{C}$, possibly the equivalence is not is not guaranteed. Much of the CAS (Computer Algebra System) software is extremely conservative and tries not to assume that variables always represent real numbers.

Comment: Trebor's and @Davius's remarks together resolves the question. Well, maybe except for why their presumably common algorithm is not neutralising those three negative signs not in the denominator.

Comment: “Radical”ly… I see what you did there

Comment: @insipidintegrator What?

Comment:  I was just referring to the fact that you used a pun. Your function has radicals, and you said ‘radically’ different…