# Need help solving trigonometric equation for all values between 0 and 360 degrees

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am having some problems with the two following questions. I was wondering if someone could check my work or offer some insight.

Solve the equation $22\cos^4{(\theta/2)}=3$ for all positive values  of ${\theta} $ between 0 and 360 degrees

My solution is:

$$\cos^4({\theta}/2)=(3/22) \\
\cos({\theta}/2)=({3/22})^{1/4} \\
-((1+ \cos{\theta)}/2)^{1/2}=({3/22})^{1/4} \\
\cos{\theta}=-(((3/22)^{1/4*2}*2)-1)\\
{\theta}=74.8$$

Values for ${\theta}=105, 195$

---

Solve the equation $\sin{\theta}=1-6 \cos{\theta}$ for all positive values of $\theta$  between 0 and 360 degrees.

My solution is:

$${\sin{\theta}}^{2}=({1-6 \cos{\theta}})^{2} \\
{\sin^2}{\theta}=1-12\cos{\theta}+36\cos^2{\theta} \\
1-\cos^2{\theta}=1-12\cos{\theta}+36\cos^2{\theta} \\
0=37 \cos^2{\theta}-12 \cos{\theta} \\
0= \cos{\theta}(37 \cos{\theta}-12) \\
\cos{\theta}=0=90, 270 ~\text{deg} \\
\cos{\theta}=(12/37) \\
\theta=71.1, 289 ~\text{deg}$$

Comment: Where are the difficultish problems ?

Comment: For the first, solve directly for $\dfrac\theta2$.

Comment: What problems do you have?

Comment: I think I did it wrong. I was wondering if someone could offer some insight on how to solve these.

Answer (score 2):

$$\implies\cos^2\dfrac\theta2=\sqrt{\dfrac3{22}}$$

$$\implies\cos\theta=2\cos^2\dfrac\theta2-1=\sqrt{\dfrac6{11}}-1<0$$

$$\theta=360^\circ n\pm\arccos\left(\sqrt{\dfrac6{11}}-1\right)$$

Finally, use [How do I prove that $\arccos(x) + \arccos(-x)=\pi$ when $x \in [-1,1]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1224415/how-do-i-prove-that-arccosx-arccos-x-pi-when-x-in-1-1)

Comment: Thanks that was helpful.