# $\int \arcsin\sqrt{1-x^2} dx$ - how to evaluate?

Tags: integration

I've been trying to solve this integral 
$$
 \int \arcsin\sqrt{1-x^2}\, dx,
$$
but got an expression with an absolute value of $x$. How can I solve this integral?

Comment: What exactly did you try?

Comment: I did a similar thing to @Mycroft, but I got a different derivative for $f(x)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you got an absolute value, my guess is that what you did was $x=\cos y$ and $\mathrm dx=-\sin(y)\,\mathrm dy$. So, you got$$\int\arcsin\left(\sqrt{1-\cos^2y}\right)\,\mathrm dy=-\int\arcsin\left(|\sin y|\right)\sin(y)\,\mathrm dy.$$Don't worry about it. Deal with it as if $\sqrt{1-\cos^2y}=\sin y$ and therefore $\arcsin\left(\sqrt{1-\cos^2y}\right)=y$. All will be fine.

Comment: Why the down vote? This is a short answer... Were you expecting a full explanation on why it works?

Comment: I didn't down vote

Comment: @Combinatoric "you" is the person who down voted... Not implying in any way that it was the author of the OP.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos: Do you say to don't worry about the absolute value because the integral is indefinite so we can suppose that we are in the interval where $\sin y$ is positive to find the antiderivative? Or are there other reasons? It has been a doubt for a while for me. Thanks.

Comment: Since we are dealing with $\sqrt{1-x^2}$, we are assuming that $x\in[-1,1]$. So, if we do the substitution $x=\cos y$, it is natural to assume that $y\in[0,\pi]$, in which case $\sin y\geqslant0$.

Answer (score 2):

Integration by parts.

$$f(x) = \arcsin(\sqrt{1-x^2})$$
$$g'(x) = 1$$

By the rule you get

$$\int 1 \cdot \arcsin\sqrt{1-x^2}\ \text{d}x = x\arcsin\sqrt{1-x^2} + \int x\cdot \frac{x}{1-x^2}\ \text{d}x$$

The latter integral is rather simple, so you can proceed from here. ($x > 0$)

Comment: How did you calculate the derivative of $f(x)$, I didn't really get it

Comment: @Combinatoric How can you NOT know the derivative of $\arcsin$ function? What kind of professor do you have? lol

Comment: @PierreCarre Right! Going to edit, thanks!

Comment: I know the derivative of arcsin, but you ignore the fact that you divide x by the square root of $x^2$, so it may differ by the sign..

Comment: @Combinatoric I do not ignore. I just supposed $x > 0$.

Comment: Ok, so I got the same thing at first place but thought you were dealing with the absolute value in another way. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Let's do the $x\ge0$ case first. Integrate by parts with $u=\arcsin\sqrt{1-x^2},\,v=x$ so the integral is$$\begin{align}x\arcsin\sqrt{1-x^2}-\int x\frac{d}{dx}\left(\arcsin\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)dx&=x\arcsin\sqrt{1-x^2}+\int\frac{xdx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\\&=x\arcsin\sqrt{1-x^2}-\sqrt{1-x^2}+C.\end{align}$$Now for the general problem. Since the original integrand is even, the antiderivative is an odd function $+C$. So the general antiderivative is$$x\arcsin\sqrt{1-x^2}-\frac{|x|}{x}\sqrt{1-x^2}+C.$$The fraction is also denoted $\operatorname{sgn}x$ or $\operatorname{sign}x$.

Comment: how did you got rid of x? you get $x/\sqrt{x^2}$ but $x$ might be negative so it's like $x\|x|$. I must be missing something.. can you help?

Comment: @Combinatoric See edit.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\arcsin\sqrt{1-x^2}=y$

As $\sqrt{1-x^2}\ge0, 0\le y\le\dfrac\pi2$

$x^2=\cos^2y$

As $\cos y\ge0$

if $x\ge0, x=\cos y, y=\arccos(x)=\dfrac\pi2-\arcsin x$

if $x<0,x=-\cos y, y=\arccos(-x)$

Using [How do I prove that $\arccos(x) + \arccos(-x)=\pi$ when $x \in [-1,1]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1224415/how-do-i-prove-that-arccosx-arccos-x-pi-when-x-in-1-1),
$$y=\pi-\arccos x=\pi-\left(\dfrac\pi2-\arcsin x\right)$$

Alternatively, $$y=\dfrac\pi2-\arcsin(-x)=\dfrac\pi2+\arcsin x$$

Now integrate by parts

$$\int\arcsin x\ dx=\arcsin x\int\ dx-\int\left(\dfrac{d(\arcsin x)}{dx}\int\ dx\right)dx$$