# Calculating $\cos^{-1}{\frac{3}{\sqrt10}} + \cos^{-1}{\frac{2}{\sqrt5}}$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

$$\cos^{-1}{\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}} + \cos^{-1}{\frac{2}{\sqrt 5}}= ?$$

Let $\cos^{-1}{\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}}=\alpha,
 \cos^{-1}{\frac{2}{\sqrt 5}}=\beta$ then, $\cos\alpha=\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}, \cos\beta=\frac{2}{\sqrt5}$

Therefore $$\cos\alpha=\frac{3\cdot2}{2\sqrt2\sqrt5}= \frac{3}{2\sqrt2}\cdot\cos\beta$$

This is all I did till now. Could you go further with this to answer?

Comment: Think about $\cos(\cos^{-1}x+\cos^{-1}y)$.

Answer (score 3):

Use trig identity: $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$  $$\implies\sin\alpha=\sqrt{1-\cos^2\alpha}=\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}\right)^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}\quad \forall \quad 0\le\alpha\le \frac{\pi}{2}$$
$$\implies \sin\beta=\sqrt{1-\cos^2\beta}=\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\right)^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\quad \forall \quad 0\le\beta\le \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Now, use trig identity
$$\cos(\alpha+\beta)=\cos\alpha\cos\beta-\sin\alpha\sin\beta$$
$$\cos(\alpha+\beta)=\frac{3}{\sqrt {10}}\frac{2}{\sqrt 5}-\frac{1}{\sqrt {10}}\frac{1}{\sqrt 5}
=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$$

$$\implies \alpha+\beta=\cos^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}=\frac{\pi}{4}
\quad \quad\left(\because \cos(\alpha+\beta)\in[-1,1]\right)$$
$$\therefore \cos^{-1}{\frac{3}{\sqrt {10}}} + \cos^{-1}{\frac{2}{\sqrt 5}}= \color{blue}{\frac{\pi}{4}}$$
Or alternatively use trig identity
$$\sin(\alpha+\beta)=\sin\alpha\cos\beta+\cos\alpha\sin\beta$$
$$\sin(\alpha+\beta)=\frac{1}{\sqrt {10}}\frac{2}{\sqrt 5}+\frac{3}{\sqrt {10}}\frac{1}{\sqrt 5}
=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$$

$$\implies \alpha+\beta=\sin^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}=\frac{\pi}{4}
\quad \quad\left(\because \sin(\alpha+\beta)\in[-1,1]\right)$$
$$\therefore \cos^{-1}{\frac{3}{\sqrt {10}}} + \cos^{-1}{\frac{2}{\sqrt 5}}=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{4}}$$

Comment: Added a line for clarity. Let me know what you think. Previously, it was not clear that $\cos(\alpha+\beta)=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\implies\alpha+\beta=\cos^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$

Comment: Fine, you defined the conditions

Comment: Perhaps you should add extra clarification how you found $\sin \alpha$ and $\sin \beta$

Comment: @ChubbyChef: I added the details as you asked for.

Comment: Type `$\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}$` to obtain $\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: Thanks for pointing out typo. I fixed it now.

Comment: This is a nice solution.

Comment: My always best regards for a very nice user...and good health.

Answer (score 3):

Hint : apply this formula:

$$\cos^{-1} x +\cos^{-1}y=\cos^{-1}[xy-\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)}]$$

Put $x=\frac2{\sqrt {10}}$ and $y=\frac 2{\sqrt 5}$

Comment: very unique idea..excellent.I prefer to your answer.Thanks.

Comment: @sirous,   Put $x=y=-1,$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
Using your notation, try using trigonometric identities to expand
$$\begin{align} \cos (\alpha+\beta) \\ \sin(\alpha+\beta)
\end{align} $$

Answer (score 0):

### Like [Proof for the formula of sum of arcsine functions $ \arcsin x + \arcsin y $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672575/proof-for-the-formula-of-sum-of-arcsine-functions-arcsin-x-arcsin-y),

using $\cos(A+B)$ and the definition of [principal values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values)

$$\cos^{-1}x+\cos^{-1}y=\begin{cases}\cos^{-1}(xy-\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)}) &\mbox{if }\cos^{-1}x+\cos^{-1}y\le\pi \\
2\pi-\cos^{-1}(xy-\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)})  & \mbox{otherwise }  \end{cases}$$

Now $\cos^{-1}x+\cos^{-1}y\le\pi$ will happen

$\iff\cos^{-1}x\le\pi-\cos^{-1}y=\cos^{-1}(-y)$ using [How do I prove that $\arccos(x) + \arccos(-x)=\pi$ when $x \in [-1,1]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1224415/how-do-i-prove-that-arccosx-arccos-x-pi-when-x-in-1-1)

$\iff\dfrac\pi2-\sin^{-1}x\le\dfrac\pi2-\sin^{-1}(-y)$

$\iff\sin^{-1}x\ge\sin^{-1}(-y)$

$\iff x\ge-y$